# Push inside AJAX Success not updating ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat that loops over $scope.events, and in the success function in ajax, it pushes a json string into the $scope.events array. However, the indexes that are pushed in the success function don't show in ng-repeat, but the index {name:"test", date:"test"} are shown. 
HTML:

```
   <li ng-repeat="event in events"><
text class="Name" ng-bind="event.name"></text><text class="Date" ng-bind="event.date"></text>
</li>
```

JS:

```
var table_important = angular.module('table-important', []);
table_important.controller('important-ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.events = [{name:"test", date:"test"}];    
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data:{"d":""},
            url: "/getImportantEvents",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {                 
                $.each(data.arr, function() {                                      
                $scope.events.push( {name:this.name, date:this.date} );


  });
            },
            error: function(e) {                
                console.log(e);
            }
        });    

});
```

Comment: Do a console of `this.name` and check its value.

Comment: Console.log(this.name) shows the correct value. Also I verified that the array contains the pushed values.@brk

Comment: Use the AngularJS $http service. The jQuery `.ajax` method is not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc...